# HTML img tag and meta viewport

Tags: html, viewport, meta

I'm currently working on a responsive website using `meta` tag viewport. I encountered an issue in which images loaded using `img` tag lose quality. But if I use `background-image` instead, they load perfectly.

I want to use `img` tag because of the SEO keywords. Is there any way to prevent it from lose quality?

EDIT: showing the markup

inside head:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

inside body:

```
<img src='images/logo.png' style='width:65px;height:65px;' />
```

the `logo.png` dimensions are 65x65 pixels

Comment: How so, lose quality? Can you screenshot the difference?

Comment: It's like the images on mobile devices looks a little bit pixelated, as if they were upscaled, but I'm actually setting the width and height in the css, to the exact width and height of the image. Example, if the image is 65 x 65, the CSS says width:65px;height:65px

Comment: please show the markup

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your `<img>`s are getting upscaled. This is probably controlled by a CSS rule somewhere that may have one or more of the following properties declared:

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

If that's the case, then simply remove those property declarations, or you could kill a fly with an RPG and try:

```
img { width: auto !important; }
```

However, this approach may end up causing you more grief in the long-run and should be avoided if possible.